# Can VHDL alias be created to contain several different concatenated std_logic_vectors?

Tags: vhdl

The alias is basically an alternative name for something. Now assume that I want to create alternative name for a bunch of things like this:

```
alias myalias : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) is a(3 downto 0) & b(1 downto 0) & c & d;
```

Is this allowed in VHDL? From my understanding, it is not.

Comment: No it is not allowed. The expression is not a named entity. IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.6 Alias declarations6.6.1 General "An alias declaration declares an alternate name for an existing named entity."

Comment: [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this just a wire?

```
entity Whatever is port (
  a : in std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
  b : in std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
  c : in std_logic,
  d : in std_logic);
end Whatever;

architecture x of Whatever is
  signal myalias : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  myalias <= a(3 downto 0) & b(1 downto 0) & c & d;
end x;
```

Comment: This adds a delta cycle delay over renaming via an alias. If the OP can accept that, fine. (Won't make any difference to synthesis anyway). If they had some reason for requesting an alias over this, that was unstated in the question.